# bash script for checking to see .AWK extension

Tags: bash, wildcards, test

```
if [ ! $var  = " *.awk " ] ; then 
            echo "$var contains awk file"
            fi
```

this is what I have but when I run it and put a file name without `.awk` it still says contains awk file

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`, you can perform a globbing test using

```
if [[ $var == *.awk ]]; then
    echo '$var ends with ".awk"'
else
    echo '$var does not end with ".awk"'
fi
```

Note the double square brackets and equal signs.

`bash` also supports the standard way of doing such tests:

```
case $var in
    *.awk) echo '$var ends with ".awk"' ;;
    *)     echo '$var does not end with ".awk"' ;;
esac
```

Note that in both cases, the pattern `*.awk` can not be quoted.  Quoting the pattern would make it a string comparison, not a globbing pattern match.

The reason that your test seems to always succeed is twofold:

1. You test against the literal string  `*.awk`  (including a space on either side) which will presumably never match, and
2. You negate the test with `!`.